# react-select how to add hidden type on option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, react-select

I want to show text on option to be like header on dropdown and add type hidden on it for can't click abled on

```
 <Select
    placeholder="Selected"
    options={Options}
    theme={selectReactTheme}
    value={selectedOption}
    onChange={onSChange}
 />
```

for Options is array OptionBasetype

```
const Options = [
  {value:0 ,label: 'Item (ID)'},
  {value:1 ,label: 'Item1 (ID:01)'},
  {value:2 ,label: 'Item1 (ID:02)'},
  {value:3 ,label: 'Item1 (ID:03)'},
]
```

Problem:
for value: 0 I want to show on header in option dropdown and hidden (can't click or select on this value)

Comment: are you looking for header label for your items? if yes, you can make use of grouping. here is the example and see if it is what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-beaver-8v07k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: oh thats good thanks